# When I am trying to install metasploit by following this tutorial an error shows up on my computer

Tags: ubuntu, metasploit

Here is a picture of my error code on metasploit:

[image]

Here is my error:

```
  An error occurred while installing openssl-ccm (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot
  continue.
  Make sure that `gem install openssl-ccm -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.

   gem install openssl-ccm -v 1.2.1
   ERROR:  Error installing openssl-ccm:
   openssl-ccm requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

I tried to install it but it stil throws an error.

Comment: this question would be considered off topic on information security because it does not relate to information security problems.

Comment: Hi there.  "I tried to install it but it stil throws an error."  You tried to install what exactly?  Ruby v2 or greater?

Comment: Have you already done `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` .  You can also `ruby -v` to check current version

Comment: it says ruby 1.8.7

Comment: still throws error after doing sudo apt-get install ruby-full